# Measuring RTT for TCP in linux kernel

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I'm implementing TCP-like RTT estimation in a custom protocol. When I look in the function

```
static void tcp_rtt_estimator(struct sock *sk, long mrtt){
long m = mrtt; /* RTT */
```

For the first iteration, when no previous RTT estimates have been done, the code snippet is

```
srtt = m << 3;          /* take the measured time to be rtt */
```

Why isn't the value of `m` taken directly for `srtt`? As per my understanding, the parameter `mrtt_us` is just the value in jiffies for the current round-trip time measurement.

Is the above assumption about `mrtt_us` incorrect? If yes, then what value should I pass to this function?

P.S.- I've the measured RTT in jiffies which I'm currently passing to this function. Obviously, this is incorrect as the first `srtt` value becomes something other than the measured rtt because of `srtt = m << 3`

Comment: Isn't it part of smoothing algorithm applied to RTT value passed into the routine? Probably requires reading the paper linked in comments in the source code: http://ee.lbl.gov/papers/congavoid.pdf

Comment: Yes, but the smoothing algorithm dictates that the first RTT measurement should be used directly as SRTT and the appropriate formulas should be used from the secong RTT measurements. Section 2.2 in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6298

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out from one of the mail chains on LKML at https://lkml.org/lkml/1998/9/12/41

It mentions that the stored SRTT is actually 8 times the real SRTT. I think it's done in such a way to provide higher precision in calculations.

So to answer the question, the measured value of RTT should be passed to this function in jiffies (Kernel version 3.13)